# Java Blackjack card images won't show up

Tags: java, swing

So I am working on my final project for my Comp Sci class in high school and I get the Jframe to pop up with all the buttons but the deal, hit and stand buttons don't work. It is supposed to be able to take a bet and then deal a new hand with the cards showing up. I am able to bet but when I deal a new hand the cards don't show up and I can't hit or stand.
Keep in mind that I am still a beginner so please don't roast me too bad.
This is the board class:

```
package blackjack;
public class BlackjackBoard {
    /**
     * Instance variables needed for a one-player blackjack game.
     */
    private Deck deck;
    private BlackjackHand myHand;
    private BlackjackHand dealerHand;
    private int myTotal;
    private int dealerTotal;
    private int myMoney;
    private int myBet;
    private int winner;
    // The message to the user. It will change as the game is played and buttons
    // are clicked.
    private String message;
    // Write the constants needed to initialize the deck.
    // Be sure to use lower case when writing the words.
    /**
     * The ranks of the cards for this game to be sent to the deck.
     */
    private static final String[] RANKS = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace" };
    /**
     * The suits of the cards for this game to be sent to the deck.
     */
    private static final String[] SUITS = { "spades", "diamonds", "clubs",
            "hearts" };
    /**
     * The values of the cards for this game to be sent to the deck.
     */
    private static final int[] POINT_VALUES = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10,
            10, 10, 1};

    /**
     * Creates a new BlackjackBoard instance.
     */
    public BlackjackBoard() {
        deck = new Deck(RANKS, SUITS, POINT_VALUES);
        myHand = new BlackjackHand();
        dealerHand = new BlackjackHand();
        myTotal = 0;
        dealerTotal = 0;
        myMoney = 100;
        myBet = 0;
        message = "Place your bet.";
    }

    public void bet(boolean gameInProgress) {
        if (!gameInProgress) {
            if (myMoney <= 0) {
                message = "You cannot bet any more.";
            } else {
                // Write the code to change the appropriate
                // instance variables with a bet of $1.
                myBet++;
                myMoney--;
                message = "Continue to bet or press \"Deal New\".";
            }
        } else {
            message = "You cannot change your bet.";
        }
    }

    public boolean dealNewGame(boolean gameInProgress) {
        if (!gameInProgress && myBet > 0) {
            message = "";
            gameInProgress = true;
            // Write the code for the initial deal (player, dealer, player,
            // dealer).
            Deck deck = new Deck(RANKS, SUITS, POINT_VALUES);
            myHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            dealerHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            deck.shuffle();
            ;

            dealerHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            myHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            dealerHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            // Now test for a dealer blackjack.
            if (dealerHand.hasBlackjack()) {
                // Code for what happens if the dealer has blackjack.
                dealerBlackjack();
                dealerWins();
            } else {
                if (myHand.hasBlackjack()) {
                    myBlackjack();
                    iWin();
                } else {
                    // There were no blackjacks. Write the code to update
                    // the total instance variables.
                    myTotal = myHand.getBlackjackValue();
                    dealerTotal = dealerHand.getBlackjackValue();
                }
            }
        } else if (!gameInProgress && myBet == 0) {
            message = "Please place a bet first.";
        } else {
            message = "You must finish this game first.";
        }
        return gameInProgress;
    }

    public void clear(boolean gameInProgress) {
        if (gameInProgress) {
            message = "You must finish this game first.";
        } else {
            myHand.clear();
            dealerHand.clear();
            myBet = 0;
            myTotal = 0;
            dealerTotal = 0;
            message = "Place your bet";
        }
    }

    public boolean hit(boolean gameInProgress) {
        if (gameInProgress) {
            // Deal an additional card to the player, find the new total,
            // and clear any messages.
            myHand.addCard(deck.deal());
            myTotal = myHand.getBlackjackValue();
            if (myTotal > 21) {
                message = "Bust. ";
                // What method call should be here?
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            message = "You must bet and deal first.";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean stand(boolean gameInProgress) {
        if (gameInProgress) {
            // Get the dealer total.
            // Use the while loop to draw cards for the dealer.
            // The dealer hits on 16 and below, stands on 17 and above.
            dealerTotal = dealerHand.getBlackjackValue();
            while (dealerTotal < 17) {
                {
                    // Deal a card to the dealer and find the total.
                    dealerHand.addCard(deck.deal());
                    if (dealerTotal > 21)// What code goes here?:)
                    {
                        winner = 2;
                        message = "Dealer busts. ";
                        // Who wins? Which method should be called.
                        dealerWins();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // Check for a winner. Careful with the return value.

                message = "";
                if (winner == -1) {
                    // Who won? Call the appropriate method.
                    dealerWins();
                } else if (winner == 2) {
                    // Who won? Call the appropriate method.
                    iWin();
                } else {
                    // Who won? Call the appropriate method.
                    push();
                }
            }
        } else {
            message = "You must bet and deal first.";
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void payout() {
        // Write code to add the winnings (or losings) to myMoney.
        if(winner == -1){
            myMoney -= myBet;
        }
        if(winner == 2){
            myMoney += myBet;
        }
        winner = 0;
        myBet = 0;

    }

    private void dealerBlackjack() {
        message = "Dealer has Blackjack! ";
        this.dealerWins();
    }

    private void myBlackjack() {
        message = "You have Blackjack! ";
        this.iWin();
    }

    private void dealerWins() {
        message = message + "Dealer wins.";
        winner = 0;
        this.payout();
    }

    private void iWin() {
        message = message + "You win.";
        winner = 2;
        this.payout();
    }

    private void push() {
        message = "Push.";
        winner = 1;
        this.payout();
    }

    // Write each of the getter methods below.
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getMyMoney() {
        return myMoney;
    }

    public String getMyBet() {
        return Integer.toString(myBet);
    }

    public BlackjackHand getMyHand() {
        return myHand;
    }

    public BlackjackHand getDealerHand() {
        return dealerHand;
    }

public Card getCard(BlackjackHand theHand, int location) {
    return theHand.getCard(location);
}
}
```

And this is the error it is giving me:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Card image not found: "cards/4diamonds.GIF"
                                at blackjack.BlackjackGUI.repaint(BlackjackGUI.java:157)
                                at blackjack.BlackjackGUI.actionPerformed(BlackjackGUI.java:251)
                                at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
                                at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
                                at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
                                at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
                                at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
                                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                                at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
                                at

 java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where does the string `cards/4diamonds.GIF` come from? (I get the `4`, I get the `diamonds`; but all the rest) It's quite obvious that the file just can't be found; but it's not clear why it's looking for that file at all.

Comment: My GUI class. It was already implemented when the program was assigned.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37262937/java-blackjack-project

Comment: That thread is kind of dead

Comment: See the comment I left on the post that gpasch linked to.

Comment: @pdskflksjd Your file paths are incorrect

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.